# Why does Google not show my new app engine web application in the search results? Does it take a while for the crawler to find the page?

Tags: search, web-crawler

Why does Google not show my new app engine web application in the search results? 
Does it take a while for the crawler to find the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a page to appear in the search results it has to have sufficiently large [Page Rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)

Very very roughly, a page has a higher page rank if many high ranked (important pages) link to it. You can read more details (as far as they are known to the general public) on the above link.

Otherwise, you have to give very very specific search terms to find your page.